Are humorous remarks in posts okay?
I have posted an answer to a question, that included a joke and serious information. The humor was clearly constrained to what i would call a short witty remark, clearly marked as humor by following it up with

only joking... sort of...

Despite the cheekiness, I think it can be called a clearly marked humorous remark.
A mod then removed that humorous remark leaving the rest of the answer intact.
Leaving aside the question of qualifying my wittiness, humorousness or otherwise quality of my answer:
Are humorous remarks in questions or answers not allowed, contrary to the community guidelines, or just generally discouraged in order to keep a dry (and constructively depressive) tone?
(Cutting braces included as a service to editors.)

I have no problem with humour in posts, and have used it myself from time to time.

I don't know why that post was edited in that I cannot see inside the head of the moderator who edited it, but I can see one possibility: your joke could have been (I would presume unintentionally) perceived as insulting to some individuals who might pursue the activities mentioned to relieve anxiety, because "procrastination" has almost exclusively a negative connotation. You're implying that someone who gardens or cleans to relieve their anxiety is procrastinating doing something else.
More generally, I think humor is fine, but you have to be aware of who your joke could be at the expense of, and given the unfortunate stigma that persists around mental illness, there are some topics on this particular stack that are less conducive to humor.
I think humor is best used in the Q&A format if it helps make a point related to the actual answer, whereas your joke didn't really add anything besides the joke.

I agree with @BryanKrause and @ArnonWeinberg that humour is fine, to a point.
I too have used a little humour in the past, but care is definitely needed within this stack as there can be serious topics of discussion here within the field of mental health. However, I don't see the need for extra special care per se here in comparison to other stacks.
You need to bear in mind the "be nice policy" within StackExchange otherwise known as the Code of Conduct, and bear in mind that what can be seen as a little humour can be extremely offensive to some others.

Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online.
        — Stack Exchange Code of Conduct

Saying that, procrastination in a sense can be a valid answer to your linked question in my view, and therefore a little explanation (even just a link to a webpage) as to why that would be a possible valid answer may have alleviated any concern for any possible offense taken by the addition.
